# how to rotate an image back and forth in android

Tags: android

hai i want to rotate an image back and forth. But now it is happening only one side.After the image reach the destination suddenly it will come back to its original position.I am using animation for rotation. Somebody help me to do this.

Comment: Maybe show us the code you are using to try to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to enable fill on your animation, then enable "fill after." You can do this by calling setFillEnabled(true) then setFillAfter(true).